# How make glassfish start in a reboot?

Tags: glassfish, amazon-ec2, glassfish-3, cloud-hosting

I have a machine in Amazon EC2 service, sometimes my machine is restarted, then I lost my glassfish and then my web apps.
How could I make it start with the system ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out "asadmin create-service". You can run "asadmin create-service --help" or check out the documentation: [admin guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2416/gglqp.html#scrolltoc) / [reference guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2433/create-service-1.html).  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks dude, I create the service then I start it, reboot my machine just to be sure that's working and it is. Thanks!

Comment: @JohnClingan: how do I make it work when my master password is not the default one and I want to run it not as root?